Finite subgroups of multiplicative complex numbers.
In "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics" as part of problem 2.1, Szekeres asks: "Find all finite subgroups of the multiplicative complex numbers $\dot{\mathbb{C}}$."
The official solution he gives is the following:

For the multiplicative complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, if $\lambda \in G$ and $|\lambda| \neq 1$ then the numbers $\lambda^n$ form a sequence of increasing magnitude if $|\lambda| > 1$, or decreasing magnitude if $|\lambda| < 1$. In either case they form an infinite set. Hence a finite group $G$ can only consist of complex numbers of unit magnitude, $|\lambda| = 1$. Writing $\lambda = e^{ia}$, if $G$ is a finite group then for some integer $n$ we must have $\lambda^n = e^{ina} = 1$. Thus $a = 2\pi/n$, and the group $G$ is a cyclic group of the form
$$
G = \{e^{2\pi i/n}, e^{4\pi i/n}, \ldots, e^{2k\pi i/n}, \ldots, e^{2\pi i} = 1\}.
$$

However, I think this is incomplete. If we think of $\lambda$ as rotations on the complex unit circle, this only considers consecutive rotations that go around the circle precisely once. However, I think we should also include rotations where we do not precisely land on a $2 \pi$ rotation on the first go around, but do on a subsequent go around. I believe this is evident in that $e^{i n a} = 1$ is satisfied by $a = 2 \pi m / n$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, I think the complete solution should be that $\lambda = e^{2 \pi i m / n}$ is a generator of the finite cyclic group and so valid subgroups consist of
$$
\begin{equation}
  \langle e^{2 \pi i m / n} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \land n \neq 0\rangle.
\end{equation}
$$
Am I correct?
Note that I've tried to use generator notation here. Basically, I'm attempting to convey that $e^{2 \pi i m / n}$ generates the cyclic subgroup, with the constraints on $m$ and $n$ that $m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \land n \neq 0$. But, please correct me if this is invalid notation.

What you have written down is, indeed, a finite subgroup of the complex numbers. And it is equal to one on the previous list. Use the Euclidean algorithm.

You are not wrong, but it's not necessary to do more. If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, you can always find $k$ such that $mk = np+1$ for some nonnegative integer $p$. Then $[e^{2i\pi m/n}]^k = e^{2i\pi/n}$ - this recovers the cases in the solution. If $m,n$ are not coprime, you can simplify it to the coprime case.

@Tri - That would make a great answer.

@JonathanZ Oh, I think it is more like a hint than a full answer, so I put it here. I will make a change then.

@pontius Please do not create new tags without first discussing it with the community.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/

I disagree with everyone saying "it's not necessary to do more". Yes, the provided solution happens to give the correct set of groups, but the proof, particularly the statement "Thus $a = 2\pi/n$", is blatently wrong as the question points out. The solution needs to be expanded to account for the situation when $a = 2\pi m / n$ and show you still get the same set of groups in order to be correct.

You are not wrong, but it's not necessary to do more as you will just repeat the groups in the solutions. If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, you can always find a nonnegative integer $k$ such that $mk = np+1$ for some nonnegative integer $p$. This $k$ can be computed explicitly using Euclidean algorithm.
Then $$[e^{2i\pi m/n}]^k = e^{2i\pi p}\cdot e^{2i\pi/n},$$ which recovers the case in the official solution. If $m,n$ are not coprime, then $m/n = m_1/n_1$ for some $m_1,n_1$ coprime, so you simplify to the coprime case since $e^{2i\pi m/n}=e^{2i\pi m_1/n_1}$.

The other answers explain the situation well but here's another take on it. Let $z = e^{it}$ be a member of the finite group where $t > 0$ is minimized. Then each $e^{ikt}$ where $0 \leq kt < 2\pi$ is also in the group. If there were any $e^{iu}$ in the group other than these, where $0 < u < 2\pi$, then $kt < u < (k + 1)t$ for some $k$ with $0 \leq kt < 2\pi$. But then $e^{i(u - kt)} = e^{iu} (e^{it})^{-k}$ is also in the group and
$0 < u - kt < t$, contradicting the minimality of $t$.

I also find that the solution is incomplete.
Remember, that usually not all elements in a cyclic group will be generators. Your proof should at least not imply that.

(WRONG PROOF) Take any finite group $G$ (not necessarily a subgroup of the nonzero complex numbers with multiplication). Take any $\lambda\in G$. Since $G$ is finite, there is an exponent $n$ such that $\lambda^n = 1$ where $1\in G$ is the neutral element. So $G$ is a cyclic group given by:
$$G = \{ \lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots, \lambda^k, \ldots, \lambda^n = 1 \}$$

So now, with words very similar to those in the "official solution", I have proved that all finite groups are cyclic!!
Nah, this argument only shows that the subgroup generated by a single element is cyclic, which is rather trivial. So the solution quoted does not appear complete, to me.

Why exactly follows that $G$ is cyclic if $\lambda^n=1$?

@schiepy I think that the point he wanted to make: it is wrong to conclude that G is cyclic from just the observation that $\lambda^n=1$.

Ah, alright. Gotcha. Maybe I should read the whole answer.

@schiepy, as I kind of spoiler, I added "(WRONG PROOF)" to the section, to make it more obvious.

Because students will often just transcribe whatever you put on the board into their notes, on those rare times that I wrote something incorrect on the board (to dissect why it was wrong) I'd have to write ***BAD WRONG MATH*** next to it. :-)

It is a very standard fact that if $K$ is any field (not just the complex field) every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $K^\times$ is cyclic.
In particular, when $K=\mathbb{C}$ a finite subgroup $G<\mathbb{C}^\times$ is always generated by a root of $1$. Namely
$$
G=\langle e^{2\pi i/n}\rangle
\qquad\text{if $|G|=n$.}
$$
Then it is an immediate consequence of the theory of cyclic groups that we have
$$
G=\langle e^{2k\pi i/n}\rangle
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\mathrm{GCD}(k,n)=1.
$$

It's indeed the groups generated by the $e^{2\pi i\theta}$ where the  $\theta $ are rational.
But it is rather obvious that those are included already,  since $e^{2\pi i m/n}=({e^{2\pi i/n}})^m$ are just powers of the so-called primitive ones that the author listed.

You repeated the OP's observation. To show the other way around, that $\langle e^{2\pi i m/n} \rangle = \langle e^{2\pi i / \gcd(m,n)} \rangle$ requires the chinese remainder theorem or Euclidean algorithm or a related idea.

EDIT 1
In this answer, I proved that the full sets in the groups generated by $e^{2 \pi i m / n}$ and $e^{2 \pi i / n''}$ are equal. But, we don't need to do this explicitly. It is enough to show that the generator is equal and then the sets, and therefore groups, must be equal. This is what Tri did, and that's a better answer.

I think this answer is probably equivalent to Tri's answer, but it was helpful for me to work this out using a few more steps.
We want to show that $\langle e^{2 \pi i m / n}\rangle = \langle e^{2 \pi i / n''}\rangle$. First, consider two cases: (1) where $\gcd(m,n)=1$ (i.e., $m$ and $n$ are coprime) and (2) where $\gcd (m,n) \neq 1$ (i.e., $m$ and $n$ are not coprime). In case (2), divide $m$ and $n$ each by their greatest common factor such that $m/n = m'/n'$, where $\gcd (m', n') = 1$. Now, we prove the equality of
$$
\begin{equation}
  \{e^{2 \pi i m' k / n'} \mid k = 0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}
   = \{e^{2 \pi i k / n''} \mid k = 0, 1, \ldots, n''-1\}.
\end{equation}
$$
In order for these sets to have the same cardinality, which is a precondition for them being equal, $n' = n''$. Additionally, we know that $e^{i \phi}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. So, we can reframe this equality as
$$
\begin{equation}
    \{m' k \mod{n'} \mid k = 0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}
     = \{0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}.
\end{equation}
$$
We can prove this by proving that (1) for each $k$ in $0, 1, \ldots, n'-1$ and for arbitrary values of $m'$ and $n'$, $m' k \mod{n'} \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}$, and (2) that there are no duplicate elements in $\{m' k \mod{n'} \mid k = 0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}$.
Condition (1) is obviously true since the set of residue classes of $x \mod{n'}$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ are $[0], [1], \ldots, [n'-1]$; i.e., equal to the elements of the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n'-1\}$.
To prove condition (2), we look for two values of $k$, $k_1$ and $k_2$ where $k_1 \neq k_2$ such that $m' k_1 \mod{n'} = m' k_2 \mod{n'}$. This equation is true when we can find some integer $l \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  m'k_2 - m'k_1 = m' (k_2 - k_1) = ln'.
\end{equation}
$$
To find values of $k_2 - k_1$ and $l$ such that this equation is equal, we need to find the least common multiple of $m'$ and $n'$. We can relate the least common multiple to the greatest common divisor with $\mathrm{lcm}(m',n') = m' n' / \gcd (m',n')$. But, as we already required, $\gcd(m',n') = 1$, so $\mathrm{lcm}(m',n') = m' n'$. Therefore, eqn (1) is true when $k_2 - k_1 = n'$ (and $l = m'$). This proves condition (2), since the $n'$ successive values of $k$ starting from $k=0$ produce unique values of $m' k \mod{n'}$.
